# How to get latest version of SPFx web part?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, spfx, content-query-web-part

I have a web part this is on version 2.0.0.0, but the site it's deployed on is still on version 1.0.0.0.

The screenshot below proves it's using the outdated version, but I can't see how to make the site use an updated version?

Help please :D

[image]

Comment: Where did you deploy the solution? Tenant level app catalog or Site collection level app catalog or at the both levels? You can try from "Site Contents" page & see if update option is available there.

Comment: Go to-> Site content->Select the app you want to update-> click on Remove-> I will to take to classic site experience -> select App>  click on ellipsis  and select about app-> Get Button appear if you have installed new version of app-> Click on Get Button.

Answer (score 0):

Go to-> Site content->Select the app you want to update-> click on Remove-> I will take to classic site experience -> select App> click on the ellipsis and select about app-> Get Button to appear if you have installed the new version of app-> Click on Get Button.

Thank you Rajat Sahani! That worked :)